# error comming while add to cart using textarea in magento 2.3.5

Tags: product, module, addtocart, sku, magento2.3.5-p1

I am facing this kind of error while creating module for custom add to cart in magento 2.3.5.

So can anyone have idea then please share with me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please update the question with your code and error you are facing?

Comment: thanks Bhaumik but error is solved by me.

Comment: You can close the question if you are not accepting the answer. Also, it would be great if you update the question with error and answer so it will be helpful to someone with a similar issue. Thanks.